# Values lost when sent to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to send my EmailFormModel, which contains the Ressurs-list, to the controller where i want to do stuff with it. However I'm never able to access the values in my EmailFormModel in my controller. I tried to overcome this problem by using Sessions, but still it doesnt work. 
The list Ressurs contains several Ressursbehov, but there is never more than one EmailFormModel.

**My controller**

```
namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class AppController : Controller
    {
        const string SESSION_SAVED_MODEL = "savedModel";
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL] = new EmailFormModel();                  
            return View(Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL]);
        }
        public ActionResult Sent()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model)
        {
            //other irrelevant code
            if (Request.Params["Ekstra_Ressurs"] != null)
            {
                model.Ressurs.Add(new RessursBehov());
                Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL] = model;
            }  
        }
        return View(model);
    }    
}
```

**My model**

```
namespace WebApplication6.Models
{
    public class EmailFormModel
    {
        [Required, Display(Name = "Prosjektnummer")]
        public string Prosjektnummer { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name = "Prosjektnavn")]
        public string Prosjektnavn { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name = "Prosjekttype")]
        public string Prosjekttype { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name = "Prosjektleder")]
        public string Prosjektleder { get; set; }
        public List<RessursBehov> Ressurs = new List<RessursBehov>() 
        { 
            new RessursBehov() };
        }
        public class RessursBehov
        { 
            [Required, Display(Name = "Ressurstype")]
            public string Ressurstype { get; set; }
            [Required, Display(Name = "Navn på ressurs")]
            public string Navn_På_Ressurs { get; set; }
            [Required, Display(Name = "Ukenummer")]
            public int? Ukenummer { get; set; }
            [Required, Display(Name = "Antall timer")]
            public int? Antall_Timer { get; set; }
            [Required, Display(Name = "Antall uker")]
            public int? Antall_Uker { get; set; }
        }
    } 
}
```

**My View**

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.EmailFormModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Registrer nytt prosjekt";

List<SelectListItem> prosjektTypeListe = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Prosjekt", Value = "Prosjekt" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Forvaltning", Value = "Forvaltning" }
    };

 List<SelectListItem> ressurstypeliste = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "utvikler", Value = "utvikler" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "frontendutvikler", Value = "frontendutvikler" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "epi-utvikler", Value = "epi-utvikler" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "webnodesutvikler", Value = "webnodesutvikler" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "designer", Value = "designer" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "rådgiver", Value = "rådgiver" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "prosjektleder", Value = "prosjektleder" }
    };
}
<div class="title">
<div class="text-center">
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
</div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="rows">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Prosjektnummer, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prosjektnummer, new { @class = "html_label" })               
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Prosjektnummer)
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Prosjektnavn, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prosjektnavn, new { @class = "html_label" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Prosjektnavn)
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Prosjekttype, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prosjekttype, prosjektTypeListe, "-- Velg Prosjekttype --",  new { @class = "dropdown" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Prosjektleder, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" }) <!--tar inn m som parameter og returnerer m.prosjektleder-->
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prosjektleder, new { @class = "html_label" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Prosjektleder)
        </div>
    </div>



    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Ressurs.Count; i++)
    {


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Ressurstype, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Ressurstype, ressurstypeliste, "-- Velg ressurstype --", new { @class = "dropdown" })
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Navn_På_Ressurs, new { @class = "col-md-2 text-right" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Navn_På_Ressurs, new { @class = "html_label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Navn_På_Ressurs)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Ukenummer, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Ukenummer, new { @class = "html_label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Ukenummer)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Timer, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Timer, new { @class = "html_label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Timer)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Uker, new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Uker, new { @class = "html_label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i].Antall_Uker)
            </div>
        </div>
    }



    <br />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Legg til ressurser" name="Ekstra_Ressurs" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send inn mail" name="Sendknapp" />
        </div>                        
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Remove `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Ressurs[i])` (and then get rid of all the unnecessary `Session` stuff)

Comment: Inside the `Html.BeginForm()` call you should also specify the controller/action as well as `POST`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy, Its not necessary since its being submitted to the `[HttpPost]`method with the same name.

Comment: You also need to change it to `public List<RessursBehov> Ressurs { get; set; }` (the `DefaultModelBinder` does not set fields, only properties). And then you initialize your model (including adding items to the collection) in the controller and pass the model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I believe thats the root of the problem. But how do I get around it? Do I have to write a custom modelbinder or is there some other easier way?

Comment: No. Just make the changes I noted above and everything will work out of the box.

Comment: And while you at it get rid of that code in your view and do it correctly by generating your `SelectList`'s in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reach model in HttpPost Index action
1) You should pass EmailFormModel type model to View in the GET Index action method.

```
EmailFormModel model     = new EmailFormModel();  
Session[SESSION_SAVED_MODEL]=model;  
return View(model);
```

2) You should use Model at the lambda expressions

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Prosjektleder, new { @class = "html_label" })
```

change all ms with Model.

Comment: This has nothing to do with it, And do use capital M `Model` in an expression

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is add @Name in html attribute then you wont need to use session also .

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prosjekttype, prosjektTypeListe  , "-- Velg Prosjekttype --", new { @class = "dropdown" , @Name = "Prosjekttype" })
```

Comment: This is completely wrong -  the `DropDownListFor()` method already adds `name="Prosjekttype"` and you never never attempt to override the `name` attribute unless you want your app to fail.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Did you executed the code after making this change ? Please dont comment unless you execute the code.

Comment: @HerSta can you confirm your problem is solved by this ?

Comment: OMG. Try to create a dropdownlist with and without adding `new { @Name = "Prosjekttype" }` - it generates exactly the same html! And OP does not need to conform that it wrong because it is. And I already solved the problem in the comments to the question.

Comment: It is because modelbinder is not able to pick up the correct name.I am confident because i reproduced the problem at my end.Why u need session when MVC is giving you proper way do we really need to use session in MVC. is it the correct approach?

Comment: Unbelievable. Read the comments in the question. Not only is this completely wrong and bad code, it has nothing at all to do with the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke do we really need a model binder for binding simple dropdown list with custom select list think on it ?Please try to reproduce the problem at your end ,

Comment: You still have not bothered to read the question or the comments. The issue is to do with the collection property named `Ressurs` not binding in the POST method (because OP had it as a field, not a property - and the `DefaultModelBinder` does not set the values of fields). It has absolutely nothing to do with the dropdownlist which is working fine.

Comment: Hey OP here. Stephen Muecke solved the problem. It was indeed the problem with the modelbinder, Can't believe i overlooked that, but oh well... the Modelbinder does not bind fields.